An exception was thrown while deserializing the token. The antiforgery token could not be decrypted
We are encountering an issue where users who log into our Blazor Server application with two-factor authentication (2FA) using Google Authenticator experience disconnection after approximately 40 minutes. The error message displayed is:

An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
I'm on .NET 8 and I do not know what cause this error. The user was filling a form in an authorized page and when he submitted he was getting an error. When I looked in the logs, I saw the message above. How should I fix this?

This is in my Program.cs:
    builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(ops =>
    {
        ops.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        ops.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

I was thinking that the user will keep the connection for at leats 30 days...
My goal is to be able to permit my logged user to rest connected over 30 days with their cookies, even if he is connecting with personnal account or with oauth2.0
